# Is it known how large (in miles) was the encampment of the Jews in the desert?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

Was there any minimum/maximum requirements for space between each individual family, the tribes, the Tabernacle and the place around the Tabernacle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yoma 75b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.75b.14?lang=bi):

> As it is written: “And they camped by the Jordan from Beth-Jeshimoth to Abel-shittim” (Numbers 33:49), and Rabba bar bar Ḥana said: I saw that site and it was three parasangs in length.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_and_Talmudic_units_of_measurement#Length_and_distance), one Talmudic parasang is equivalent to 2.41 - 2.85 miles. So three parasangs are in the region of 7.2 - 8.6 miles.

Comment: According to Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, an *amah*equals 21.25 inches. A *parsah* is 8000 *amot*, so therefore 21.25*8000/12/5280 = 2.68 miles approximately. 3 would be 8.04 mi.